# c++ Как открыть файлы в проводнике и получить имена выбранных файлов?

Tags: c++, qt

Мне надо открыть файлы в проводнике и получить имена этих файлов. Записать их имена в "Line Edit", попутно скопировав файлы в папку лежащею в корне программы. Как это реализовать еще и для Windows и для Linux.

Я делаю так:

```
...
    ui->dateEdit->setText(QDate::currentDate().toString());
...
    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_9_clicked()
    {
        QString File = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
                    this,
                    tr("Открыть файлы"),
                    "C://",
                    "All file (*.*);;"
                    );
        QString fileName = QFileInfo(File).fileName();
        ui->PhotoLineEdit->setText(fileName);
        QFile file(File);
        QString newDir = QString("../%1/photo/").arg(QString(ui->dateEdit->text()).replace(" ","_"));
        qDebug()<<newDir;
        file.copy(newDir + fileName);
    }
```

Но тут открывается только один файл и не копируются фотографии в папку `"../Ср_мар_21_2018/photo/"`.

Comment: `QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames ()`, а по поводу копирования — проверь, что директории существуют и не забывай, что путь указывается относительно cwd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось так :

```
  void MainWindow::on_pushButton_9_clicked()
    {
        QStringList Files = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(
                    this,
                    tr("Открыть файлы"),
                    "C://",
                    "Все файлы (*.*);; Файлы изображений (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"
                    );
        QStringList filesName;
        QString newDir = QString(QDir::currentPath()+"/%1").arg(QString(ui->dateEdit->text()).replace(" ","_"));
        QDir().mkdir(newDir);

        for (int i=0; i<Files.size();i++) {
            filesName.append(QFileInfo(Files.at(i)).fileName());
            QFile::copy(Files.at(i),newDir+"/"+QFileInfo(Files.at(i)).fileName());
        }
        ui->PhotoLineEdit->setText(filesName.join(","));
    }
```

Это для Windows , если у кого есть идеи для Linux напишите ).